# Como alterar o payload do JWT no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, jwt

Preciso alterar meu `payload` do meu `JWT` para ficar igual ao exemplo abaixo.

```
{
  "iat": 1566408228,
  "exp": 1566426828,
  "email": "fulano@mail.com",
  "name": "Fulano Silva",
  "roles": [
    "manager"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Se usa algum pacote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Model User

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

// Meu model agora implementa o JWTSubject
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject{

    // Adicionei essa função
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}
```